# Python Socket issue

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer

I am working on this function on my client side to grab files from my server and I am having some issues. I am getting this error: `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` on my server side and on my client side everything looks fine. On the server side it says that stockwatchlist has been sent as well as the first one in my file list in the `for` loop, but when I look at the stockwatchlist file it is empty and the other file is not in there. Any help will be much appreciated.

Client Side:

```py
def ClientGetInitalize():

    s = socket.socket()
    host = '10.250.10.208'
    port = 80
    s.connect((host,port))
    print('Connected to Server for File Transfers')

    fileList = 'StockWatchList.txt'
    sotckwatchfile = open(fileList, 'wb')
    file_data = s.recv(1024)
    sotckwatchfile.close()
    print('Recived Stockwatch File List')
    file = open('StockWatchList.txt','r')
    filelist = []

    for row in file:
        watchfile = row.strip('\n')
        watchfile = watchfile.strip('stock_CSV\\')
        watchfile = 'stock_CSV/' + watchfile
        filelist.append(watchfile)


    for file in filelist:
        if not os.path.isdir('stock_CSV'):
            os.mkdir('stock_CSV')
        openfile = open(file, 'wb')
        file_data = s.recv(1024)
        openfile.close()
        print(file, 'Has been Received successfully')
```

Server side

```py
import socket

stockwatch = 'StockWatchList.txt'
filelist = []

file = open(stockwatch, 'r')

for row in file:
    watchfile = row.strip('\n')
    watchfile = watchfile.strip('stock_CSV\\')
    watchfile = 'stock_CSV/' + watchfile
    filelist.append(watchfile)

while True:

    s = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 80
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(1)
    print('Waiting for any incoming connections')

    conn , addr = s.accept()
    print(addr, 'Has connected to the server')

    openfile = open(stockwatch,'rb')
    file_data = openfile.read(1024)
    conn.send(file_data)
    print(stockwatch, 'Has been sent successfully')

    for file in filelist:
        openfile = open(file,'rb')
        stock_data = openfile.read(1024)
        conn.send(stock_data)
        print(file, 'Has been sent successfully')
```

Comment: You aren't actually writing anything into any of your files on the client side.  In particular, StockWatchList.txt is always empty.  Even if you add the necessary `.write()` calls, your entire approach is fundamentally broken - TCP is a *stream* protocol, and you have absolutely no indication within your stream of the boundaries between the files.  There is no connection between the amount of data written in a single `.send()`, and the amount received by a single `.recv()` - the parameter is merely a maximum size, it will return however many bytes are available at the moment.

Comment: Ok I will put in the `.write()` in thank you for reminding me. But how do I set boundaries between the files? So that all my data is sent and revived correctly?